# Condition for non-negative sectional curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, conformal-geometry

Is there any equivalent condition for a metric to have all sectional curvatures less or equal to zero?

Basically, I have done some conformal perturbation on a Riemannian metric of negative sectional curvatures and I was trying to find an argument that implies that the sectional curvatures are still non-negative without brutal force calculations on every pair of vectors.

I know it is quite a general question, but I could not find anything in this direction.

Comment: Have you tried to compute the sectional curvature of the perturbed metric?

Comment: Hi, @Deane! Yeah! That is the point, I could prove that for two specific vector fields $X, Y$ I have $K(X,Y)\leq0$. That was not easy at all! Doing brutal force computations for general $X, Y$ does not seem doable because it depends on so many terms.

Comment: You should try before you ask here. Long messy calculations are necessary when doing differential geometry.

Comment: @Deane it has been almost 1 month that I am trying it. That is why I am trying to find some other argument that helps.

Comment: Since you have told us nothing specific about the original metric (besides that it is negatively curved) and the conformal factor, the answer to your question is negative.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am afraid you are right.

Answer (score 3):

For any Riemannian manifold $(M,\mathtt{g})$ and smooth function $\rho\colon M\to \Bbb R$, the sectional curvature $\widetilde{K}$ of $\widetilde{\mathtt{g}} = {\rm e}^{2\rho}\mathtt{g}$ is given in terms of the sectional curvature $K$ of $\mathtt{g}$ via the formula $$\widetilde{K}(\Pi) = {\rm e}^{-2\rho}\big(K(\Pi) - {\rm tr}_{\mathtt{g}_x|_{\Pi}}(B^\rho_x|_{\Pi})\big),\tag{1}$$for all $x\in M$ and $\Pi \in {\rm Gr}_2(T_xM)$, where the twice-covariant symmetric tensor field $B^\rho$ on $M$ is given by $$B^\rho = {\rm Hess}_{\mathtt{g}}\rho - {\rm d}\rho\otimes {\rm d}\rho + \frac{\|{\rm d}\rho\|_{\mathtt{g}}^2}{2}\mathtt{g}.\tag{2}$$
The proof of this fact is a brute force computation using the well-known formula for the curvature tensor $\widetilde{R}$ of $\widetilde{\mathtt{g}}$ in terms of the curvature tensor $R$ of $\mathtt{g}$, namely, that $$\widetilde{R} = {\rm e}^{2\rho}R - 2\widetilde{\mathtt{g}} \wedge B^\rho.\tag{3}$$ Here, $R$ and $\widetilde{R}$ are fully covariant and $\wedge$ stands for the curvaturelike-tensor valued Kulkarni-Nomizu product between twice-covariant symmetric tensor fields, given in coordinates by $$2(T\wedge S)_{ijk\ell} = T_{jk}S_{i\ell} - T_{ik}S_{j\ell} + S_{jk}T_{i\ell} - S_{ik}T_{j\ell}.\tag{4}$$

You can probably figure out what happens if you focus on traces of $B^\rho$, but $(1)$ suggests that you might need more conditions on $\rho$.

Comment: I am familiar with those relations. I am mostly using the relation from Walschap's book that looks nicer to me. The problem is not really using some relation, but proving the sign of $\tilde{K}(\Pi)$ for any $\Pi$. I have some conditions on $\rho$ to make life less painful, but still a mess doing the calculations in general. Usually, you get things like $\Gamma_{ij}^k\partial_k\rho$, so you can control how the sign of $\partial_k\rho$ changes asking for some conditions, but $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ can have any sign in general. I know I may be asking too much ;p.  I may post it on MO with more details.